# disabled angular2 routes caching

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have 2 components: projects and companies.

Every project contains up to 25 companies.

For example:

I have one project and 25 companies in it.
If I select the first project and move to companies' `Component`s, I will see the companies list.

Then, when I move back to projects list and move to companies' list again several times, the page will be freezing more and more. It seems like the old components' versions are being stuck in memory. So when I'm changing the components using routes they are being recreated, but the previous version of them is not removing.

How can I disable this "caching"?

Comment: The problem is, most probably, in your code, and not caused by some caching problem that you imagine to explain the cause of your problem. If you want help, post a minimal complete example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad, i forgot to write `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in the component decorator.